# Gulp serve takes too long to build

Tags: gulp, microsoft-teams, yeoman, gulp-watch, yeoman-generator

After creating the project using yo teams and upon running the `gulp serve` command the command takes **1-2 mins** to build on every save. I don’t know what is the main reason but I have disabled multiple things and tried other options too make it fast but no success so far. I have not change anything in the **gulp.js** and **webpack config.js** file both of them are having default configuration which were created by the process.

Any help would be appreciated on how to make the build process faster. Right now I have to wait for it to build the changes which is such a pain every time you are saving something and build process takes this much time.

Please refer below image where you can see on every save "**Webpack:client"** is getting started and it is taking ages to complete. In worst case scenarios it is taking **1.5 min** to build the process again where it should take only few seconds(1-2 sec) / milliseconds

[image]

Comment: Could you please check your package.json file if it contains an unappropriated dependency? 
Could you please remove that dependency?

Comment: I have not added any dependency it's all default which was created by the yeoman generator

Comment: Could you please connect to [Product Support Channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback#product-support-channels).